# Delete Duplicate element in array in C program

Tags: c

I have a block of code to removing duplicate element in array (it's not a sort array). Can someone analyze for me the line "j--". I dont understand how it works.

I have an array like: 1 2 3 1 1 1. Required result: 1 2 3 And what happen with the step: 1 2 3 1 (after removing some elements). When a[i] == a[j](1 == 1) with i = 1 and j = 3, how the a[k] = a[k + 1] work? I dont understand it, too. Because a[k] = a[3] is the last element, what about a[k + 1]?

Someone helps me, please. Thank you so much

```
int n, i, j, k;

// Input size of array
printf("Please enter size of array: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

int a[n];

// Input elements in the array
for(i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
    printf("Element[%d] = ",i);
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}

// Print original array
printf("The original array:\n");
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%d\t",a[i]);
}

// Find duplicate elements in array
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {                   
    for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {            
        // If any duplicate found 
        if(a[i] == a[j]) {
            // Delete the current duplicate element
            for(k = j; k < n; k++) {
                a[k] = a[k + 1];
            }
            // Decrement size of array(n) after removing duplicate element
            n--;            
            j--;
        }
    }
}

// Print array after deleting duplicate elements
printf("\n\nThe array after removing duplicate elements:\n");
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%d\t",a[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be clear, this code appears to remove **all** duplicates. Your example implies that you want to remove only **consecutive** duplicates. Which one are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This code will not work if the array is for example size 4 and the input is 1 2 3 1, then a[k + 1] will be invalid. In your case its not since the original size is 6 and this algorithm does not really delete anything, just moving the array values so then a[4] is valid.

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Comment: @bitmask it is about remove duplicate element, any duplicate, not only consecutive

Comment: @EdHeal no, it's random. I will change it to another array

Comment: Perhaps sort it first before finding the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop will indeed read the element at offset `n`, hence have undefined behavior.

Change it to:

```
        for (k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
            a[k - 1] = a[k]; // 1 2 3 1
        }
```

The index `j` is decremented after moving the rest of the array one position to the left because the next iteration should involve the new value of `a[j]`. Hence j is decremented before being incremented via the last clause of the enclosing `for` statement.

```c
// Find duplicate elements in array
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {                   
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {            
        // If any duplicate found 
        if (a[i] == a[j]) {
            // Delete the current duplicate element
            for (k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
                a[k - 1] = a[k];
            }
            n--; // Decrement size of array(n) after removing duplicate element
            j--; // Decrement the index to test a[j] again in the next iteration
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working. Should I use memory allocation ?

Comment: No, the operation can be performed in place, No need for memory allocation.

Comment: You should post a complete program to show how you handle the array and its length.

Answer (score 0):

let me explain this from first:

you check one element `a[i]` with every element after it , starting from `a[j]=a[i+1]` when this condition become true  `if(a[i] == a[j])`, means element `a[i]` is equal to one of elements after it, which means this element `a[j]` should be removed.

so in this loop:

```
   for(k = j; k < n; k++) {
                a[k] = a[k + 1];
```

you start from that position in which you found a duplicate element and copy element after it in it. `a[k]=a[k+1]` starts from `a[j]` (which was found position) and move every element in previous position.

like this `a[2]==a[3]` so `a[3]=a[4]` and `a[4]=a[5]` until `a[n-2]=a[n-1]`.

so in this process as you see `a[3]` is removed so now `a[4]` is in position `3`.

after this loop ends ,`j--` move `j` (for my example to position 2)to previous position so next time you enter this loop `for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++)` when `j++` is done ,you will again go to position you have removed data from it.(in my example j became 2 now it will again become 3) because now in position `3` there is new data(`a[4]`) so you should check it again.

also since one element was removed ,you need this `n--` for number of elements.

and then process will go on same way.

as for last element in your question `a[k]=a[k+1]` ,since `a[k]` was last element nothing meaningful will go in it`(a[k+1])`.

and since you have `n--` that is not really important ,because you will be informed about meaningful elements remained.